# embedded font issue in chrome, bottom of the customer font cut off

Tags: html, css, font-face, embedded-fonts

[image]

Hi, I have a font-face issue in chrome on windows:
This is my code:

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
      <title>All formats - fallback ordering</title>  
      <style> 
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'LCSansRegular';
          src: url('fonts/lc-sans/LC_SansRegular.eot'); 
          src: url('fonts/lc-sans/LC_SansRegular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
               url('fonts/lc-sans/LC_SansRegular.svg#LCSansRegular') format('svg'), 
                url('fonts/lc-sans/LC_SansRegular.otf') format('opentype'),
                url('fonts/lc-sans/LC_SansRegular.woff') format('woff'),
                url('fonts/lc-sans/LC_SansRegular.ttf')  format('truetype');
          font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;
      }
     h1 { font-family: 'LCSansRegular'; font-size: 36px; }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Heading 1 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Why the bottom part is cutting off on Chrome, it works fine on Chrome/ff on mac, and ff, ie9-11 on Window, but except Chrome on Windows.

Comment: What is this font? And the odds are that the problem is caused by something not shown in the question, such as a line height setting.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error, however setting h1 line-height to 1em should fix it.

```
h1 {
    line-height: 1em;
}
```